# sftp No supported authentication methods available

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I am trying to setup sftp to upload/download files from a specific directory (var/www/mysite.com)

My issue is when I try to connect using Filezilla and I get an error stating

> No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

So I think I missed a step when settup up and configuring sftp on my Ubuntu LAMP server. I should not I want to be able to sftp using a username and password and not a keyfile.

Here is what I did:
Created user with password via SSH
I then

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
```

I then

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

and inside the file set `chroot_local_user=YES` and commented out `chroot_list_enable=YES` I then restarted sftp using:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

I then configured the users directory
sudo usermod -d /var/www/mydomain.com  
note I replaced  with the username I created

I then

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and added the below to the bottom of the file

```
Subsystem  sftp  internal-sftp
Match user <username>
ChrootDirectory /var/www/mydomain.com
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

and ensure that further up in the file that this is commented out (*i.e* before the one you just added)

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

I then restarted ssh using:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

and changed permissions using:

```
chown root:root /var/www
chown root:root /var/www/mydomain.com
chmod 755 /var/www
```

Lastly I did:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mydomain.com
chmod 755 /var/www/site
```

However I am not able to login to sftp via filezilla??

When I run the ssh command:

```
sftp -vvv user@servername
```

I get the below.  I do not have a /secure in the var/log folder?

when I run the above commend I get this output

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 57: Bad configuration option: usepam
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 58: Bad configuration option: subsystem
debug2: checking match for 'user <username>' host *****.com originally *****.com
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 59: not matched 'user "*****"'
debug2: match not found
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 60: Bad configuration option: chrootdirectory
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 61: Bad configuration option: forcecommand
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 62: Bad configuration option: allowtcpforwarding
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 5 bad configuration options
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Are login attempts being logged in /var/log/secure on the server? What happens if you run this on the command line? sftp -vvv user@servername

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 60: Bad configuration option: chrootdirectory
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 61: Bad configuration option: forcecommand
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 62: Bad configuration option: allowtcpforwarding
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 5 bad configuration options
```

You put these configuration options in the `ssh_config` instead of `sshd_config`. They are not valid in the first one.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mydomain.com
```

This is also wrong, because the `chroot` directory has to be root-owned and not writable by any other user as explained in many answers and in manual page for `sshd_config`.

Comment: Thanks so I put the info in sshd_config , restarted vsftpd and then did
sudo chown -R root:root /var/www/mydomain.com and I still get the same error?

Comment: Also make up your mind if you wish to configure VSFTPD or OpenSSH. They are completely different services providing SFTP.

Comment: ahh ok thank you show I made sure I am using and editing the ssh conf files and after a restart  its now working. thanks all